# Can someone explain what this command does?

Tags: find

Can someone explain to me what this command does?

**EDIT: Do *not* run this command! It *will* break your installation.**

```
sudo find / -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: As you (originally) presented it,`-exec rm {}\;` will give a syntax error. The correct syntax requires a space between `{}` and `\;`

Comment: The command needs a `\! -type d` to not spew all those silly errors.

Comment: @oals Or redirect errors to `/dev/null`. Also check the `-delete` option of find.

Comment: I can't tell if this is a joke… or if someone told you to do it as a "joke".

Comment: On a professionally maintained and secure system it should (probably) not do anything useful.

Comment: Hmm, let me try it...

Comment: `man find` tends to have answers for things related to `find`...

Comment: This was not a joke. I happened to come across the code a few week ago and was curious what it actually did and how it worked.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Bad Things ® ™.  It's (almost) the equivalent of `sudo rm -rf /` - it will, as root, find all files or directories starting from `/` and recursively descending from there, and then execute the `rm` command against each file/directory it finds. It won't actually delete directory entries as there's no `-f` or `-r` options passed to `rm`, but it will remove all the file entries.

Hint: don't run this unless you feel like reinstalling your operating system.

Comment: Strictly speaking, at some point it will delete `/bin/rm`, and after that it will fail to delete any more files.  The suggestion by @ott to use `-delete` would fix this "bug" :-)

Comment: This avoids the built-in protection in GNU rm, which blatantly refuses to remove everything from the root downward.

Comment: Note that this command won't be equivalent to `sudo rm -rf /`. Attempt to remove `/` is prohibit by POSIX rm (busybox rm does remove `/`).

Comment: As Cuonglm said, `sudo rm -rf /` [is harmless](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html) on POSIX (and most other) systems, so no, this is not like it at all!

Answer (score 8):

Don't run it.

This will find everything (all files, directories, links, sockets etc) under `/` i.e. everything in the system and then it will try to remove those one at a time with `rm`.

Note that as there is no `-r` option with `rm`, only the directory entries will not be removed, everything else will be gone.

Comment: @cuonglm `find /` will list all files, and `-exec` executes the command on each result of `find`. So it's the `find` command doing the recursion, and `rm` is only called for each individual file.

Comment: @jozzas: No, find / list all files and directories under /, all directories left unchange, only files removed.

Comment: @cuonglm I have already mentioned that..please check second paragraph..

Comment: @heemayl: Ah, I see, sorry for my mis-reading.

Answer (score 3):

Simple! This command will remove all files in your server.

**Don't run it!**